# ASP.NET Core Data Access Layer Custom Class AddSingleton

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have my EntityFrameworkCore DBContext in **ConfigureServices**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{               
    services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(Options => ...  );
    ...
}
```

I also have my data access layer factory class which receives DBContext in constructor

```
public partial class DataAccessFactory
{
    public readonly ProductsDataAccess Products;
    public readonly CategoriesDataAccess Categories;

    public DataAccessFactory(MyDBContext db)
    {
        Products = new ProductsDataAccess(db);
        Categories = new CategoriesDataAccess(db);
    }    
}
```

In order to work with Data Access Layer, I have to create new instance of **DataAccessFactory** per each request.

My question is, does it make sence and is there any way to create one instance of **DataAccessFactory** and add it as a Singleton?

Comment: Did you create instances of DataAccessFactory using new operator?
Then you also create manually the db context. In that way you are not using DI.
Generally it is good practice to recreate db context between different requests, also it is default behavior.
In your code you already registered a MyDBContext, you can also register DataAccessFactory. [See the different way to register it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) (as singleton or any other way)

Comment: Yes I create instances of DataAccessFactory using new operator per each request, I capture MyDBContext via DI and create new instance of DataAccessFactory per each request. Now I think maybe instead of creating new instance of DataAccessFactory per each request, I can create DataAccessFactory one and Singleton it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your service inside `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<DataAccessFactory>();
}
```

and inject it where you needed:

```cs
public class MyController
{
    public readonly DataAccessFactory Factory;

    public MyController(DataAccessFactory factory)
    {
        Factory = factory;
    }    
}
```

It will be created only once per application life. If you instead will want to change it scope for example per request, just change `AddSingleton` to `AddScoped`.

**Update:**

But be careful when mixing different-scoped services. You cannot inject short living object into long living, because it will cause exceptions. In your situation you will need to change DbContext scope to singleton (sic) or consider to change Factory lifetime to Scoped. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core#ef-dbcontext-and-iunitofwork-instance-lifetime-in-your-ioc-container) is example how to change DbContext scope.

Comment: Thanks Ivvan, this was the explanation I was looking for. Article link you showed me gave me an answer to my question. I didn't know that AddDbContext adds DbContext as Scoped. Now it's clear to me how to manage my code